# Android studio minify enabled = true , not able to generate apk?

Tags: android, android-studio

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'
apply plugin: 'me.tatarka.retrolambda'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'realm-android'

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

defaultPublishConfig "debug"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.youth4work.ibps"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 23

    multiDexEnabled true

    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0.0"
}

signingConfigs {

    release {
        storeFile file('keystore/youth4work_second_key')
        keyAlias 'youth4work_second_key_alias'
        keyPassword "youth4work"
        storePassword "youth4work"
    }

    debug {
        storeFile file('keystore/debug.keystore')
        keyAlias 'androiddebugkey'
        storePassword 'android'
        keyPassword 'android'
    }
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),      'proguard-rules.pro'
    }

    debug {
        versionNameSuffix "Debug"
        debuggable true
    }
}

lintOptions {
    disable 'InvalidPackage'
    checkReleaseBuilds false
}

packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/services/javax.annotation.processing.Processor'
}

compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
```

}

```
retrolambda {
jvmArgs '-noverify'
}

dependencies {
final PLAY_SERVICES_VERSION = '8.3.0'
final SUPPORT_LIBRARY_VERSION = '23.3.0'

// Google Play Services
compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:$PLAY_SERVICES_VERSION"
compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-    analytics:$PLAY_SERVICES_VERSION"
compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:$PLAY_SERVICES_VERSION"
compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:$PLAY_SERVICES_VERSION"

// Support Libraries
compile "com.android.support:support-v4:$SUPPORT_LIBRARY_VERSION"
compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$SUPPORT_LIBRARY_VERSION"
compile "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:$SUPPORT_LIBRARY_VERSION"
compile "com.android.support:cardview-v7:$SUPPORT_LIBRARY_VERSION"
compile "com.android.support:design:$SUPPORT_LIBRARY_VERSION"
compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:23.3.0'

compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.2.0'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.2.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.2'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.2'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava:2.0.2'

compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:7.0.1'
compile 'com.jakewharton.timber:timber:4.1.0'
compile 'com.jakewharton.rxbinding:rxbinding:0.4.0'


compile 'com.github.siyamed:android-shape-imageview:0.9.+@aar'
compile 'com.github.kevinsawicki:timeago:1.0.1'
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.8.2'
compile 'com.rengwuxian.materialedittext:library:2.1.4'
compile 'com.mobsandgeeks:android-saripaar:2.0.2'
compile 'com.joanzapata.iconify:android-iconify-fontawesome:2.1.1'
compile 'com.github.jakob-grabner:Circle-Progress-View:1.2.8'
compile 'com.github.vlonjatg:progress-activity:v1.0.3'
compile 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v2.2.4'
compile 'com.daasuu:animateHorizontalProgressBar:0.2.2'

compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.1.0'
compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.1.0'
compile 'com.trello:rxlifecycle:0.4.0'
compile 'com.trello:rxlifecycle-components:0.4.0'



compile('com.github.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:0.8.5.6@aar') {
    transitive = true
}

compile('com.mikepenz:fastadapter:1.4.0@aar') {
    transitive = true
}

testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}

// Log out test results to console
tasks.matching { it instanceof Test }.all {
testLogging.events = ["failed", "passed", "skipped"]
}
```

here if i make `minify enabled = false` the code runs fine while if i use true the code shows

> Information:Gradle tasks [:app:assembleRelease] google-services plugin
>   could not detect any version for com.google.android.gms, default
>   version: 8.3.0 will be used. please apply google-services plugin at
>   the bottom of the build file. :app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE :app:checkReleaseManifest
>   :app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComAndroidSupportAnimatedVectorDrawable2330Library
>   UP-TO-DATE :app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72330Library
>   UP-TO-DATE :app:prepareComAndroidSupportCardviewV72330Library
>   UP-TO-DATE :app:prepareComAndroidSupportDesign2330Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComAndroidSupportMultidex101Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComAndroidSupportRecyclerviewV72330Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42330Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportVectorDrawable2330Library
>   UP-TO-DATE :app:prepareComDaasuuAnimateHorizontalProgressBar022Library
>   UP-TO-DATE :app:prepareComFacebookAndroidFacebookAndroidSdk482Library
>   UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComGithubAfollestadMaterialDialogsCore0856Library
>   UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComGithubJakobGrabnerCircleProgressView128Library
>   UP-TO-DATE :app:prepareComGithubSiyamedAndroidShapeImageview093Library
>   UP-TO-DATE :app:prepareComGithubVlonjatgProgressActivityV103Library
>   UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAnalytics830Library
>   UP-TO-DATE :app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBase830Library
>   UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBasement830Library
>   UP-TO-DATE :app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesGcm830Library
>   UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesMeasurement830Library
>   UP-TO-DATE :app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesPlus830Library
>   UP-TO-DATE :app:prepareComJakewhartonRxbindingRxbinding040Library
>   UP-TO-DATE :app:prepareComJakewhartonTimberTimber410Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComJoanzapataIconifyAndroidIconify211Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComJoanzapataIconifyAndroidIconifyFontawesome211Library
>   UP-TO-DATE :app:prepareComMikepenzFastadapter140Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComRengwuxianMaterialedittextLibrary214Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComTrelloRxlifecycle040Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComTrelloRxlifecycleComponents040Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareIoReactivexRxandroid110Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareIoRealmRealmAndroidLibrary0883Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareMeZhanghaiAndroidMaterialprogressbarLibrary114Library
>   UP-TO-DATE :app:prepareReleaseDependencies :app:compileReleaseAidl
>   :app:compileReleaseRenderscript :app:generateReleaseBuildConfig
>   :app:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE :app:mergeReleaseAssets
>   :app:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:processReleaseGoogleServices :app:generateReleaseResources
>   :app:mergeReleaseResources :app:processReleaseManifest
>   :app:processReleaseResources :app:generateReleaseSources
>   :app:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac Note: Some input files use or
>   override a deprecated API. Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for
>   details. Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
>   Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
>   :app:compileRetrolambdaRelease :app:compileReleaseNdk UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:compileReleaseSources :app:prePackageMarkerForRelease
>   :app:transformClassesWithRealmTransformerForRelease
>   :app:processReleaseJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForRelease
>   :app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease assmember)
>   Warning:there were 1 unresolved references to library class members.
>            You probably need to update the library versions.
>            (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#unresolvedlibraryclassmember)
>   Warning:Exception while processing task java.io.IOException: Please
>   correct the above warnings first.
>   :app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease FAILED
>   Error:Execution failed for task
>   ':app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease'.
>
> > java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first. Information:BUILD FAILED Information:Total time: 27.946 secs
> >     Information:1 error Information:91 warnings Information:See complete
> >     output in console

Answer (score 3):

If you enable minifying, the build will call Proguard to strip out every unnecessary classes, members and methods.
For this to work, you'll need a proguard config file, which will tell Proguard which classes are your entrypoint to your classes and which members and methods should be kept. 
The error you are seeing is a common error for mismatching method calls.

The error includes a link to the [Proguard](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#unresolvedlibraryclassmember) manual, describing the error a bit more: you'll have to make sure that you are using the right Android Build Target and that you keep all necessary libs and their methods.

Try to adapt the Android Build Target in your properties. If this doesn't work, you'll have to check if you need more entries in your proguard config.

Comment: Can you please elaborate with an example as i am new to proguard . Also the project i am working on is developed by someone else so i don't really know the complete project details its only 3 days since i started working on the same and my first target is to shrink the apk and remove bugs.

Comment: Well, you could start with the suggested solution in the provided Link: 
`you should change the build target in your project.properties file or build.gradle file to that recent version. You can still specify a different minSdkVersion and a different targetSdkVersion in your AndroidManifest.xml file.`
If this doesn't work you will have to have a look at your proguard-config file (add it to your question) or create one, if you don't have one.
Creating a new config from scratch for your project may be a bit tedious, since you have a lot of external libraries.

Comment: is there any separate file for proguard available in projects please provide some more details

Comment: Yes, there should be a proguard-rules.pro or proguard.cfg or progaurd.txt. This is the file referenced in your Gradle build file under "porguardFiles"
Have a look here: https://guides.codepath.com/android/Configuring-ProGuard for a good example on how to create one. There are also examples for some of the libs you are using